# How to change node version using nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am developing two projects.
Each project requires different node version.(v12, v14)
When I try to use one node version, it occurs node-sass error.
Should I uninstall v12 and reinstall v14?
I heard it can be repaired using nvm.
Somebody tell me how to switch using nvm.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nvm ls
```

Show the list of versions you have installed:

```
nvm ls
v16.19.1
v18.14.2
```

After that, you can use this command to change the version

```
nvm use default v16
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nvm list
nvm use 12.0.0
nvm use 14.0.0
```